# Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [t3]

Tags: java, jms, weblogic12c

We have a standard code that posts the messages to the weblogic queues but strangely in one of the application I am seeing this error. Any inputs that indicate why we get this error would be great.

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [t3]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:252) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:265) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:238) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:184) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using WebLogic then your problem is that you are trying to connect using the ActiveMQ client libraries which is obviously doomed to failure.  If you are trying to connect to ActiveMQ then your transport URI is incorrect as the error is telling you, the scheme prefix 't3' is not an ActiveMQ supported transport.

Given the wording in the question I'd guess you are probably configuring in the wrong ConnectionFactory type into JNDI or whatever platform you happen to be using.